# Error install RMysql RHEL 7.3

Tags: mysql, r, compiler-errors, rhel7

I am using:
R version: 3.3.3.
OS: RHEL 7.3 on EC2.
I am trying to install RMysql.
So in R terminal I submit command: install.packages("RMySQL")

First attempt was unsuccessful and gave error that **libmysqlclient was not found**.

```
Using PKG_LIBS=-lmysqlclient
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libmysqlclient was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu 16.04)
        libmariadbclient-dev (Ubuntu 14.04)
 * rpm: mariadb-devel | mysql-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: mysql56_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: mariadb-connector-c (OSX)
If libmysqlclient is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libmysqlclient.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RMySQL’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpx1vsUG/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("RMySQL") :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

So I installed mysql-devel. *(sudo yum install mysql-devel)*

After this I am trying to install RMysql again.
But that does not work again. Something is wrong with **PKG_LIBS -lmariadb.**

*gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o RMySQL.so RMySQL-init.o connection.o db-apply.o driver.o exception.o fields.o result.o utils.o -L/usr/lib64/ -lmariadb -lpthread -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
**/bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb***

Here is the whole R output.

```
* installing *source* package ‘RMySQL’ ...
** package ‘RMySQL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found mysql_config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/lib64/ -lmariadb -lpthread -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RMySQL-init.c -o RMySQL-init.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c connection.c -o connection.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c db-apply.c -o db-apply.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c driver.c -o driver.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c exception.c -o exception.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c fields.c -o fields.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c result.c -o result.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c utils.c -o utils.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o RMySQL.so RMySQL-init.o connection.o db-apply.o driver.o exception.o fields.o result.o utils.o -L/usr/lib64/ -lmariadb -lpthread -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RMySQL.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RMySQL’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpYEs7XA/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("RMySQL") :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so finally I get how to resolve this issue !!!
Proud of myself:)

I had mariadb-devel installed

> Name        : MariaDB-devel
>   Arch        : x86_64
>   Version     : 10.2.6
>   Release     : 1.el7.centos

**libmariadb.so** was misssing. 
Instead I had libmariadbclient.a. (/usr/lib64/libmariadbclient.a)
So I had to make a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libmariadbclient.a /usr/lib64/libmariadb.a
```

After this installation of RMysql was succesfull:

> ** building package indices
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>   * DONE (RMySQL)
>   Making 'packages.html' ... done